# Derive the Lorentz Transformation by solving (1).

Tags: algebra-precalculus, general-relativity

[image]

This photo and problem is taken from Zee's textbook pg. 169, Einstein's Gravity in a nutshell. Here in the moving reference frame we're moving at a velocity $u$, and the total time it takes to go from the top mirror back to the bottom mirror is given by ($\Delta t$ in the rest frame and $\Delta t'$ in the moving frame). The total displacement in the rest frame is $\Delta x=0$ since the initial and final position are the same, but in the moving frame this isn't the case. That implies (1) $c\Delta t' = 2\sqrt{(\frac{1}{2}u\Delta t')^2 + L^2}$ is the distance light travels. We also know $\Delta x' = u\Delta t'$.

Problem 1 in this section says directly from equation (1) we can get the lorentz transformations, which are:

$ct' =\frac{ct+\frac{u}{c}x}{\sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{c^2}}}$

$x' = \frac{x+\frac{u}{c}ct}{\sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{c^2}}}$

Also: $y'=y$ & $z'=z$

We also know $2L/c = \Delta t$.

Every time I apply this formula I get $\Delta t' = \gamma \Delta t$, where $\gamma = (1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})^{-1/2}$, but this I cannot match with the lorentz transf. equations. I also believe possibly $\Delta t' = t' -t$ & $\Delta x' = x' - x$ but I do not know for certain and this hasn't helped me at all.

Comment: Why can't they match?  $c \Delta t' = \gamma(c \Delta t +\frac{u}{c} \Delta x) =  \gamma c \Delta t $ since $\Delta x =0$ in the frame.

$\Delta t' $ means the time lapsed in the moving frame and $\Delta t $ means the time lapsed in the moving frame  which are **not** $t'-t$ and $x'-x$.

Comment: You're telling me the 'x' in the Lorentz Transformation (first equation) is your $\Delta x$? That this 'x' term doesn't really have to be there in the first place? Even other sites (e.g. http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/relativity/dynrel.pdf) page 111 has this term in the equation, i.e., the u/c*x term.

Comment: I've also noticed that $x'=0$ in some of the readings. Why is this? And does this help at all?

Comment: My $\Delta t = t_2 - t_1$ is the difference in time for 2 events in the rest frame, and $\Delta x= x_2 -x_1$ is the difference in space for 2 events in the rest frame.

Comment: Yeah I can see what you are saying. In general we need the 'x' there but in this problem it was constructed in such a way that we have no nonzero displacement in that specific time frame. Thanks!